# what is the order of group GL2(R), where all the entries of the group are integers mod p, where p is prime.

Tags: group-theory

what is the order  of group GL2(R), where all the entries of the group are integers mod p, where p is prime.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  What have you tried so far ? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: Shouldn't this be denoted $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ or $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ instead?

Comment: I also support the opinion of other voters that this question is missing context and other relevant pieces.

Answer (score 0):

That's $GL_2(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)$. The first column vector must be non-zero, zthe second must not be in the subspace spanned by the first vector. This gives us $p^2-1$ choices for the first column and $p^2-p$ for the second. We conclude $\|GL_2(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)=(p^2-1)(p^2-p)$,

Comment: You mean $(p^2-1)(p^2-p)$.